# Deleting and selected in the same PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to delete a post, then select and show another post with PDO. I would like to do this within one method:

```
    public function remove_and_renew_item(){
    $this->query = $this->conn->prepare('DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id=:remove_id');
    $this->query = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id=:next_id');

    $this->query->bindParam(':remove_id', $this->remove_id);
    $this->query->bindParam(':next_id', $this->next_id);
    $this->query->execute();

    echo json_encode($this->query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
}
```

However, I'm AJAX is reporting an error. Is there a problem because:

- I have two separate queries?
- It's trying to fetch the delete part of the query, too?

If I remove a single query, and it's related bindParam, it works. However, together they do not. Would anyone be able to figure out why they don't work together?

Comment: You can't do two queries at once in the same variable. You're simply replacing the variable with the second statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is incorrect - you need two entirely separate queries... you can however prepare both queries, then use them again and again later, along the lines of...

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->query1 = $this->conn->prepare('DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id=:remove_id');
    $this->query2 = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id=:next_id');
}

public function remove_and_renew_item() {

    $this->query1->bindParam(':remove_id', $this->remove_id);
    $this->query2->bindParam(':next_id', $this->next_id);

    $this->query1->execute();
    $this->query2->execute();

   echo json_encode($this->query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
}
```

Having said how to do what you want, in reality it is often better to keep methods for deleting and selecting (reading) separate, you're really adding complexity where it is not really needed.

Comment: This answer would be a lot better with an explanation using some code.

Answer (score 4):

You're overwriting the first query with the second. What you want to do isn't impossible, but the way you're doing it is broken.

```
$this->query1 = $this->conn->prepare('DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id=:remove_id');
$this->query2 = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id=:next_id');
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I still stick with one `execute()`?

Comment: No, execute is a method of the query object, of which you'll have two. You'll need to fix your bindings, too.

Answer (score 0):

Select and delete commands have to be executed separately.  This is true for any database engine.  If you want to send a single command from php, write a stored procedure with the two sql commands and call it from php.